# MySql FULLTEXT match against a list of keywords from a lookup table

Tags: mysql, match, full-text-search, against

I don't know if this is possible, but it would simplify my calculations to be able to match against each word in a lookup table with a single query. (otherwise, I'll probably pull the tables into memory and program a sequence of queries in python):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM input_form
WHERE MATCH (title,story) AGAINST (word);
```

The above will return a count for number of stories that contain 'word', but then is there some way to have it repeat this count for every word in a table containing these words?

```
SELECT 
word,
count(MATCH (title,story) AGAINST (word))
FROM keywords;
```

Something like that? Note that title and story are from one table, and word comes from another.

Comment: From the [MySQL documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) it doesn't seem as though you can do this in one query. You may be able to use a database loop, though - I believe this type of loop is called a cursor. Cursors are, however, currently beyond my scope. Note that since you're getting a count of matches, you should use [`IN BOOLEAN MODE`](http://dev.mysql.md/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html). Wish I could be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little rusty, but I think you want to use nested selects:

```
SELECT tbl.word, count(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM input_form WHERE MATCH(title, story) AGAINST (word)) as tbl;
```

You may have to add another level of nesting if I recall.

Comment: So you CAN join tables using MATCH () AGAINST () in MySql? I wasn't sure what that kind of a join would look like.

Comment: By the way - what you shared seems like a start, but it doesn't pull the words in from the 2nd "keywords" table yet.

Comment: In the light of day, I think that I may be wrong and @lunchmeat317 may be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. After a while I decided this may be near impossible in MySql, but I did use the db.cursor() and cursor.execute() method of the python MySql module inside of a loop to generate the required table, then uploaded it into the database (since doing this dynamically for a page would be crazy).